# Troubleshooting my code to send SMS using Twilio API when a donation form is submitted

Tags: node.js, twilio-api

I am trying to send SMS using twilio API but its not working

I am expecting a sms when donation form is submitted. the code runs without any error but I don't receive any SMS on my phone when i fill and submit the donation form. I am using my phone as a test.

Someone should kindly  help me resolve this.

```
const initialDistanceThreshold = 1; // Initial distance threshold in miles
        const initialTimeFrame = 5; // Initial time frame in minutes
    contract.events.DonationCreated({ fromBlock: 'latest' })
      .on('data', async (event) => {
        const donationIndex = event.returnValues.donationIndex;
        const donation = await contract.methods.donations(donationIndex).call();

       

        const message = `Address: ${donation.street_address + donation.city + donation.zip_code}-New donation: ${donation.itemDescription} - Quantity: ${donation.quantity}`;
        await sendSms(recipient, donation, initialDistanceThreshold, initialTimeFrame);

      });

    const donationCount = await contract.methods.getDonationCount().call();
    const allDonations = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < donationCount; i++) {
      const donation = await contract.methods.donations(i).call();
      allDonations.push(donation);
    }

    // console.log(allDonations);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Donation saved successfully.',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to save the donsation.' });
  }
});


async function sendSms(recipient, donation, initialDistanceThreshold, initialTimeFrame) {
  console.log('Recipient:', recipient);
  console.log('Message:', message);
  console.log('Distance Threshold:', distanceThreshold);
  
  const foodCharities = [
    { number: "+17134716087", latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194 },
    { number: "+17134716087", latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194 },
    { number: "+12026051410", latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194 },
  ];

  const donorLat = 37.7749;
  const donorLong = -122.4194;

  const donorLocation = { latitude: donorLat, longitude: donorLong };
  const charityDistances = foodCharities
    .map((charity) => {
      const charityLocation = { latitude: charity.latitude, longitude: charity.longitude };
      const distance = geolib.getDistance(donorLocation, charityLocation);
      return { number: charity.number, distance };
    })
    .filter((charity) => charity.distance <= distanceThreshold);

  if (charityDistances.length === 0) {
    console.log("No pantries found within the distance threshold");
    return;
  }

  charityDistances.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);

  const closestCharity = charityDistances[0].number;
  const message = `Address: ${donation.street_address + donation.city + donation.zip_code}-New donation: ${donation.itemDescription} - Quantity: ${donation.quantity}`;

  try {
    await twilioClient.messages.create({
      
      to: "closestCharity",
      from: "+18329797454",
      body: message,
      
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
    // console.log("SMS sent successfully");

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending SMS:", error);
    
    // Increase the time frame for the next attempt
   
  }

}
```

Comment: With which payload is this code triggered? I.e. does it ever reach the `twilioClient.messages.create()` function? And more importantly, where do you define `twilioClient`? This code seems incomplete.